# TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by' - help needed

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to select the quantity of sales on the date '2011-11-30' and sort values by the quantity

This code creates the groupby:

```
date_item_df = df.set_index('InvoiceDate').groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'StockCode'])['Quantity'].sum() date_item_df
```

This is to order by quantity:

```
last_month_sorted_df = date_item_df.loc['2011-11-30'].sort_values(by='Quantity', ascending=False).reset_index()
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'
```

Comment: `loc` returns series and series do not have `by` param in `sort_values()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html

Comment: Thank you, I've looked at the documentation but I am still unsure of how to re-add the invoice date as an index and then sort it by quantity?

Answer (score 0):

When working with a series object, you dont need to specify a `by` parameter. There is a difference between the `pandas.DataFrame.sort_values` and `pandas.Series.sort_values`

Your `date_item_df.loc['2011-11-30']` returns a series, not a dataframe.

More details here - [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [pandas.Series.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html)

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 3, 10, 5])
s.sort_values(ascending=True)
```

```
1     1.0
2     3.0
4     5.0
3    10.0
0     NaN
dtype: float64
```